# Debugging query neo4j

Tags: debugging, database-design, graph, nosql, neo4j

I am studing physical data model of neo4j for my tesis, and I want to know if Can I get detailed information about scanned relationship and nodes in a query?

Example, how nodes system should read for find a node with name='test'?

Thanks!

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17366370/neo4j-label-index-searches-with-wildcards which gives an example on displaying the execution plan for a query.

Comment: this is for java application, i am working with cypher!

Answer (score 2):

you can prefix your cypher query with `PROFILE` in the Neo4j shell.

Comment: Stefan can you explain me the result of PROFILE command?, what mean db_hits? and row?...

Comment: please be aware that PROFILE output is not documented. Reason for this is that the internal structure of cypher is optimized from one release to another which might causes changes. I'd suggest that you send your query, it's profile output and the version of Neo4j you're using in a separate question here.

Answer (score 1):

Also Neo4j is open source, so you can look for yourself: http://github.com/neo4j/neo4j

There are also some talks on Neo4j internals: http://neo4j.org/internals

And this presentation video on Neo4j Internals: https://vimeo.com/76806550